# Saving data from a text file into a struct

Tags: c, pointers, io

I am trying to create a new test_type_t struct for every line after the first line in this file that I am reading. Then I'd like for the new struct to be saved in a set for use later.

Currently I am running into a problem where the following happens. Note that the first SKU line is in fact the second line of the file.

First SKU line read -> new P(1) created -> P(1) populated with data -> P(1) added to set = productlist->head->data = P(1)

Second SKU line read -> new P(2) created -> P(2) populated with data -> P(2) added to set = productlist->head->data = P(2)

This results in me loosing P(1)’s data.

I know that set_add functions correctly as the code has been tested and given to me. I am almost certain that I am simply messing up some pointer logic somewhere. Here is the relevant code:

```c
// See how this goes I feel like 100 is overkill
char *line = (char *)malloc(100);
int count = 0;

if (inputFromFile) {
    inputFile = fopen(inputFileName, "r");

    if (inputFile != NULL) {
        while (fgets(line, 50, inputFile) != NULL) {
            if (count == 0) {
                strncpy(order.customerID,line, 12);
            } else {
                // Prodcut p really
                test_type_t *pPointer = (test_type_t *)malloc(
                        sizeof(test_type_t));
                test_type_t p = *pPointer;
                char *token;

                token = strtok(line, "\t");
                strncpy(p.SKU, token, 12);

                token = strtok(NULL, "\t");
                p.quantity = atoi(token);

                set_add(productList, &p);
            }

            // Do something with the line
            count++;
        }

        fclose(inputFile);
    }
```

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: Provide a [mcve].